# how to delete the last elements of an array in js

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a two dimensional array where the last elements are empty.
Like this:

```
data = [["1","2","3","","",""],["4","5","6","x","f",""],["7","8","9","",""]]
```

Now I want to remove the empty elements and get the correct new size with .length

I tryed it like this but it doesn't work:

```
        for (i = 0; i != data[2].length-1; i++) {
            if (data[2][i].isEmpty()) {
                data[2] = data[2].splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
```

Is there any good solution?

Comment: Take a look at [pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)

Comment: What is your desired output?  Is it `data = [["1","2","3"],["4","5","6","x","f"],["7","8","9"]]`?

Comment: Compare them to the empty string (i.e., `=== ""`), or check their length (i.e., `.length === 0`). There is no such thing as `isEmpty()` unless you've built it yourself.

Comment: Coincidentally, all the empty elements are the last ones. But if you just want to remove empties (not necessarily the last), then maybe: `noEmptys = data.map(subarray => subarray.filter(Boolean)).filter(arr => arr.length)`?

Comment: @JosephMarikle yes exactly thats the output i want and data[2].length should be 5

Comment: @R98 You want `data[2].length` to be `5` even though it only has 3 elements?? Or did you mean `data[1].length`?

Comment: @CRice yeah you are right i meant data[1] don't know how i could mess this up

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could map the arrays after filtering with `Boolean` as callback for keeping [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) elements.

```js
var data = [["1", "2", "3", "", "", ""], ["4", "5", "6", "x", "f", ""], ["7", "8", "9", "", ""]];

data = data.map(a => a.filter(Boolean));

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Using [Boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) is very clever.

Comment: thanks works perfectly for the whole array but don't work for me if i try to use only an inner array like data[2] = data[2].map(a => a.filter(Boolean))

Comment: @R98, then just filter the array, like `data[2] = data[2].filter(Boolean);` without mapping, because you have only one array for filtering.

Answer (score 2):

Splicing in a `for()` loop is tricky due to changing the lengths of the arrays

Use `map()` and `filter()`

```js
let data = [["1","2","3","","",""],["4","5","6","x","f",""],["7","8","9","",""]]

data = data.map(arr => arr.filter(e => e.trim()));  

console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
```

Comment: works totally fine for the whole array how can i use it for only one array inside data? for example data[1]?because it sadly doesnt work with that

Comment: Just use `filter` on that array. map is used to do all of them

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
const data = [
  ['1', '2', '3', '', '', ''],
  ['4', '5', '6', 'x', 'f', ''],
  ['7', '8', '9', '', ''],
];

const cleanData = data.map(arr => arr.filter(value => value || false));

console.log(cleanData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrow functions are elegant, but not fully supported at the moment, so probably following may be better solution:

```
const data = [
    ['1', '2', '3', '', '', ''],
    ['4', '5', '6', 'x', 'f', ''],
    ['7', '8', '9', '', ''],
];

const filteredData = data.map(function (arr) {
    return arr.filter(Boolean);
});


console.log(filteredData);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [["1","2","3","","",""],["4","5","6","x","f",""],["7","8","9","",""]];
var i;

for(i = 0; i < data[2].length; i++){
  if(data[2][i] == '')
  {
    var temp = data[2].slice(0,i);
    break;
  }
}

console.log(temp);
```

If you want to keep the same data structure and the pattern that each array will have a series of empty strings at the end this will find the first empty string and chop off the rest.